# Unity/ReSharper UsedImplicitly not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resharper

I'm using ReSharper 8.1 for Visual Studio 2013, while writing code for Unity 4.6.0.

As expected, functions like Update, Start and Awake are labeled as "unused".

Now, ReSharper suggests adding an Annotations.cs file, and using the `[UsedImplicitly]` annotation to ignore the warning.

The problem is... this doesn't work, I have Annotations.cs in my project, and the following code still mentions that Start is unused:

```
    [UsedImplicitly]
    private void Start()
    {
        //doStuff
    }
```

The code compiles fine, but trying to ignore this from the context menu suggests to add *another* Annotations.cs file (in this case, named Annotations1.cs, because Annotations.cs already exists).

Comment: Note that later versions of ReSharper have a [Unity Support extension](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/JetBrains.Unity/) that resolves this issue. Also, see [this related post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/157392/115296) on whether the `UsedImplicitly` attribute should be used on Unity lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you changed the namespace in the annotations file? If so, you need to tell ReSharper to look in the new namespace. Presumably, it's not finding the annotation attribute, which is why it's prompting to add another annotations.cs file.

Comment: For more helpful info about annotations and the namespace, see https://grantwinney.com/using-annotations-to-help-resharper-analyze-your-code/#Using_Annotations

Answer (score -1):

You can also put this above the method:

```
// ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
```

Comment: While correct, this doesn't address how to fix the usage of [UsedImplicitly].